# Why is the exit code 1 after I run a Perl script successfully?

Tags: perl, batch-file, exit-code

When I try running my Perl scripts, it executes successfully. Later, when I run this command `echo %errorlevel%`, it gives me the output as 1. Why?

Answer (score 6):

If Perl returned with errorlevel 1, then either `exit(1)` was called

```
>perl -e"exit 1"
>echo %errorlevel%
1
```

or `$?` was set to `1` in an `END` handler

```
>perl -e"END { $? = 1; }"
>echo %errorlevel%
1
```

or the program died when `$!` was `1`

```
>perl -e"$!=1; die;"
Died at -e line 1.
>echo %errorlevel%
1
```

(This would often indicate a system call failed with "Operation not permitted")

```
>perl -E"say $!=1"
Operation not permitted
```

or the program died when `$!` was `0` and `$?` was `(1 << 8)`.

```
>perl -e"$!=0; $?=1<<8; die;"
Died at -e line 1.
>echo %errorlevel%
1
```

I suppose it's possible for `perl` to exit with `1` under other circumstances (like problems loading `perl` itself), but I don't know of any such circumstances.

Comment: Thanks!!!!U mean there could be a exit(1) in the perl code? Can u be more clearer.

Comment: You're referring to the last paragraph? There could be a call to `exit` in `perl` itself. But like I said, I don't know of any.

Comment: I have found that there was an exit code in my perl script. I have made the changes, Thanks a lott for the help ikegami

Answer (score 1):

Something to be aware of, you must interrogate the %ERRORLEVEL% immediately.  Every step in a batch script will set or mess with the errorlevel, so if you expect it to stay around, it won't.  For instance, if you run a script, then run another command (dir, or echo, etc.) and then check the errolevel, it will be for the command AFTER the script, not for the script itself.